# Insert multiple rows of default values into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a single column, which is an auto-generated identity

```
create table SingleIdTable (
   id int identity(1,1) not null
)
```

I can insert a single row with an auto-generated id with:

```
insert into SingleIdTable default values
```

I want to insert many rows and use the output syntax to get their ids, something like:

```
insert into SingleIdTable
output inserted.Id into @TableOfIds
    select (default values) from SomeOtherTable where Attribute is null
```

Where the intention is to insert a row into `SingleIdTable` for each row in `SomeOtherTable` where `Attribute` is null using an auto-generated id. The above doesn't work, but how could I do it. I note that if my table had more than just a single column I could do it, but I can't select empty rows which is what I really want to do.

I can't change the definition of `SomeOtherTable`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If SQL Server 2008+ you can use `MERGE` for this. Example syntax below.

```
MERGE INTO SingleIdTable
USING (SELECT *
       FROM   SomeOtherTable
       WHERE  Attribute IS NULL) T
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  DEFAULT VALUES
OUTPUT INSERTED.id;
```

I'm not sure what practical use this single column table has though?

Comment: Cunning... The table an artefact of a someone misapplying NHibernate when mapping a group. I will accept this, but I now realise I could do with correlating the inner query with the insert so that I can `output inserted.id, SomeOtherTable.id)`. Is this possible? Really I just need to match my bag of generated ids each with an element of `SomeOtherTable` where `Attribute` is null. Any thoughts?

Comment: @silasdavis - Yes just use `OUTPUT INSERTED.id, T.id`

Comment: oh of course, thanks I didn't think I was going to be able to do this!

Comment: And again merge can be used as a "hack solution" for a problem. Also used this kind of a solution for matching old ID's with new ID's. Still think it's ugly but it works, better than using a cursor. Thx

Comment: A practical use of this is the Tally table: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1):

you did not specify which version of SQL Server you are on. If you happen to be on SQL 2012 you probably can replace you SingleIdTable with a sequence: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx