# How to insert into a table that specifies a DEFAULT value for every column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where all columns are auto-populated whenever an insertion happens:

```
CREATE TABLE …
(
    ItemID      INT       NOT NULL IDENTITY(…),
    DateCreated DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

How do I write a SQL statement that inserts a new row into this table without having to manually provide any concrete values to insert?

(There is already [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777362/how-to-insert-default-values-in-sql-table), but it differs in that it's about a table with some non-`DEFAULT` columns for which a value must be manually provided.)

Comment: As an honest question, what use is such a table?

Comment: The table is used to hold ItemIDs which are used in other tables as a Foreign Key. For example a Photo is an item, a Video is an item etc. The ItemID table is required to keep a unique ID across multiple tables. So when someone inserts a new Photo, it firsts adds a row to the table mentioned in my question which auto-generates a unique value for ItemID. This auto-generated value is inserted into the Photo table as an FK.

Comment: Alternative: Use a `SEQUENCE` to generate unique key values across several tables. It's a feature new to SQL Server 2012 and has some issues of its own (similar to `IDENTITY`), but requires less storage space than an extra table.

Comment: @stakx thanks for the edit. I didn't know about SEQUENCE (only heard of it) but if I do use that, then how will I have a corresponding DateTime value for when that value was created? Hence I probably do still need a table

Comment: @volumeone: Both the ID and its creation date would appear in the various item tables. `CREATE SEQUENCE ItemId …; CREATE TABLE BlobItems (ItemId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR ItemId, DateCreated DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(), …);` Every one of your item tables would have identical column definitions for `ItemId` and `DateCreated`. If that's not what you want, then you're probably better off with your current schema.

Comment: [and to insert multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863711/73226)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `DEFAULT VALUES` option:

```
INSERT INTO IdentitySpecification
DEFAULT VALUES;
```