# How to save new value if a Unique Constraint is violated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I have a table with a column named PAN that has a unique constraint. I looking for a way to auto increment the largest value stored in PAN by 1 if the constraint is violated by trying to insert a duplicate record in the column.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Most like it you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. But again not sure about what/why are you trying to do

Comment: SQL Server supports auto-increment using the identity property. Anything self-written is very likely to fail in a multi-user / multi-threaded environment.

Comment: To me it looks like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Does PAN contain meaningful information?  Or is it just a surrogate key?  The whole point of a unique constraint is to prevent the action that you seem to be trying to allow.

Comment: Rolling your own incrementing number is fraught with issues. Either use an identity or a sequence.

Comment: there isn't a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger in `SQL Server`

Comment: @SeanLange Sequence was introduced in 2012 version... It's possible (and quite easy) to [mimic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319922/3094533) to some extent in 2008, though...

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is pretty clever but not without issue. I was able to produce a deadlock pretty easily while testing it for concurrency.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually, I've never tested this code myself. It was just a proposed solution to that specific problem (though a better solution would be to replace the DBA that "doesn't believe in identity columns")...

Answer (score 0):

One way, as one of the comments suggested, is a INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER.

Another way is by putting your INSERT in a TRY..CATCH structure.