# How to insert 100 rows to a single table with only identity column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to insert 100 rows to the following table using a single query?

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEST1 (TEST_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
```

I tried below code

```sql
DECLARE @numRows int,@i int
SET @numRows = 100
SET @i=1

WHILE @i<@numRows
begin
    INSERT #TEST1 SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sysobjects a
    SET @i=@i+1
end
```

but it is not working.

Comment: what have _you_ tried, where are _your_ code?

Comment: What below code? @ShajuMadheena

Comment: your table does not have any other column ?

Comment: Why you have tagged c#. No c# code in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST1 (TEST_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEST1 ON;

DECLARE @numRows int,@i int
SET @numRows = 100
SET @i=1

WHILE @i<@numRows
BEGIN
    INSERT #TEST1(TEST_ID) SELECT @i
    SET @i=@i+1
END
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEST1 OFF;

SELECT * FROM #TEST1
DROP TABLE #TEST1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I cannot think of a way of doing this with one statement.  You could use the table `master.dbo.spt_values`:

```
set identity_insert #test1 off;

insert into #test1 (test_id)
    select top (100) row_number() over (order by (select null))
    from master.dbo.spt_values;

set identity_insert #test1 on;
```

The specific problem is that `select` needs to return *something*, and that something can't be a non-value for a non-column.  And the alternative `values` syntax only inserts one row at a time.

You might be better off doing:

```
create table  #test1 (
    test_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    dummary varchar(1)
);

insert into #test1 (dummy)
    select top (100) cast(NULL as varchar(1))
    from master.dbo.spt_values;
```

This uses a minimal amount of space, because a `NULL` `varchar()` only occupies space for the `NULL` bit.

For your code, `default values` will work:

```
WHILE @i<@numRows
begin
    INSERT #TEST1 DEFAULT VALUES
    SET @i=@i+1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This option does not require `set identity_insert on`.
Using merge will allow you to use `default values` for multiple rows:

```
MERGE INTO  #TEST1 
USING 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM sys.objects
) S
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  DEFAULT VALUES;
```

(Thanks again to Martin Smith for the merge trick on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863422/insert-multiple-rows-of-default-values-into-a-table))

The advantage here is that this does not assume anything about the identity column, or even the existence of one - it can be used to insert the default value to whatever columns you have on the table, be it a single `int identity(1, 1)`, or even many columns.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/MSBJ55384)

Answer (score 1):

Or just simply this:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1 DEFAULT VALUES
GO 100
```

Run this in SQL Server Management Studio and you'll get 100 rows inserted into `#Temp1`

Comment: `GO` is just an artificial instruction existing only in SSMS and a few other client tools. Nice for an ad-hoc query, but not for use from a client program.

Comment: @Alejandro: correct - `GO` is a *batch separator* that works in SSMS and in the SMO libraries. The question also was about SSMS - not about an arbitrary client program ...

Comment: I can't see SSMS being mentioned anywhere in the question nor in its history.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below :

```
            //replace server namd and instance with name in login window for SQL Server Management Studio (ssms)
            //replace database name wit you database
            string connectionString = "Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO [dbo].[#TEST1] (TEST_ID) VALUES ({0})", i);
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Identity column does not allow direct inserts!!